# Limit Nginx max concurrent connections

Tags: nginx

I am looking for a way to limit the number of maximum concurrent connections to 1.
I do not want a connection limit per IP, I already know this is supported.

As far as I can see, [max_conns](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#max_conns) would be exactly what I'm looking for, but unfortunately it's not available in the free version:

> Additionally, the following parameters are available as part of our
>   commercial subscription

Limiting `worker_connections` is not an option, as the minimum it wants is 4, and it affects more than the incoming requests.

My conf:

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  localhost;

location / {
rewrite_by_lua '
     [some lua code]
';

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Literally moments after I posted this question, I stumbled upon [this](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/restricting-access/) while googling for how to whitelist IPs from a file in Nginx! Kind of funny considering I spent the last 2 hours googling for specific terms about rate limiting; talk about relevance, heh..

```
limit_conn_zone $server_name zone=servers:1m;
limit_conn servers 1;
```

This in the `http {` block seems to do the trick.

Comment: See also http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_conn_module.html#limit_conn